# Difference between select="./node()" and select="node()" in DSpace's item-view.xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath, dspace

Inside of statements that `select` a `dim:field` in DSpace's [item-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl), I find

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

in context:

```
<xsl:for-each select="dim:field[@element='description' and @qualifier='abstract']">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="node()">
         <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </xsl:when>
```

as well as

```
<xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
```

in context:

```
<xsl:for-each select="dim:field[@element='identifier' and @qualifier='uri']">
   <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
         <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

and I wonder if there is any difference between `node()` and `./node()` in this setting, and if so, what difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

The expressions `./node` and `node` are equivalent.